# How do the Objects in this code work?

Tags: java

```
public class MainClass
{
    private String name="";

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<String>();
        String str=new String("abc");
        al.add(str);
         str="def";
        al.add(str);
         str="ghi";
        al.add(str);
         str="jkl";
        al.add(str);
        System.out.println(al);

        ArrayList<MainClass> al1=new ArrayList<MainClass>();
        MainClass mainclass=new MainClass();
        mainclass.setName("Abhi");
        al1.add(mainclass);
        mainclass.setName("Sajith");
        al1.add(mainclass);
        mainclass.setName("Sridhar");
        al1.add(mainclass);

        for(MainClass main:al1)
            System.out.println(main.getName());
     }
}
```

output:

```
[abc, def, ghi, jkl]
Sridhar
Sridhar
Sridhar
```

Why my object is getting overriding in second case when it is not happening in first case?

Comment: You only ever create one `new MainClass();` object so you should expect that when you set it with three different values you are setting this one object. You should be able to step through the code in your debugger to understand exactly what is happening.

Comment: Whether you use `new String` or use a string literal, you have four different Strings in your first case, so when you add those references you still have 4 different strings.

Comment: Note that ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<String>(); is same as ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<>(); and bad practice to String str=new String("abc"); but do String str = "abc";

Comment: for the first case it´s a mix of `String` beeing immutable, but mainly that java works with pass-by-value and that you don´t have a chance to modify the previous references of `str` by reassigning it.

Comment: Thanks for the replies..could you kindly explain why in first case the list is having 4 different references and in second case it is pointing to a single reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<String>();
    //a1 is empty ArrayList of Strings.
    String str=new String("abc");
    //str is now a reference to "abc"
    al.add(str);
    //a1 has now reference to "abc"
    str="def";
    //str has now reference to "def"
    al.add(str);
    //a1 has now reference to "abc" and reference to "def"
    str="ghi";
    //str has now reference to "ghi"
    al.add(str);
    //a1 has now three different references
    str="jkl";
    //str has now reference to "jkl"
    al.add(str);
    //a1 has now four different references.
    System.out.println(al);

    ArrayList<MainClass> al1=new ArrayList<MainClass>();
    //al1 is now empty
    MainClass mainclass=new MainClass();
    //mainclass has now reference to an object with an empty String
    mainclass.setName("Abhi");
    //mainclass' reference didn't change. It's still the same, however the string is different
    al1.add(mainclass);
    //al1 has now one reference to the mainclass
    mainclass.setName("Sajith");
    //mainclass' reference didn't change. It's still the same, however the string is different
    al1.add(mainclass);
    //al1 has now two references to the mainclass
    mainclass.setName("Sridhar");
    //mainclass' reference didn't change. It's still the same, however the string is different
    al1.add(mainclass);
    //al1 has now three references to the mainclass

    for(MainClass main:al1)
        System.out.println(main.getName());
```

So, your first `ArrayList` has four different references which point to different values. You second ArrayList has three times the same reference, to the `mainClass` which at the end represents a `String` which is "Sridhar".